# Smart Lock request always RESOLUTION_REQUIRED with single account

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

I only have a single credential saved in my app using Smart Lock, but I still get the account resolution alert every time:

[image]

[Smart Lock docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-credentials) seem to imply this alert should only appear if the user has multiple options to choose from.

**Why am I seeing this alert with only one credential saved?** More specifically, when I call `Auth.CredentialsApi.request`, why is my `credentialRequestResult` status `RESOLUTION_REQUIRED` with only one stored credential?

Comment: Have you checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34538439/2556660

Comment: Yes, that question was about something different.

Comment: Check Settings > Google > Smart Lock for Passwords and ensure that Auto Sign-In has not be disabled for any of the accounts on the device (use account selector at the top to check each account, or check this account setting at passwords.google.com for each account on the device). And of course, make sure that the disableAutoSignIn has not be called for the app on this device (we track that state in Play Services) and you need a save or selection to clear that state (or clear Play Services data)

Comment: @StevenSoneff thank you. I didn't have "Auto sign-in" turned on. If you want to put that comment in an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Settings > Google > Smart Lock for Passwords and ensure that Auto Sign-In has not be disabled for any of the accounts on the device (use account selector at the top to check each account, or check this account setting at [passwords.google.com](https://passwords.google.com) for each account on the device).

And of course, make sure that the `disableAutoSignIn` has not be called for the app on this device (we track that state in Play Services); and you need to do a save or selection to clear that state (or clear Play Services data)